# sql for Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am dealing with a huge volume of traffic data. I want to identify the vehicles which have changed their lanes in MS Access database. I want to identify those records only which has changed the lane (immediate two records: before lane change and after lane change)

Traffic Data:

```
Vehicle_ID   Lane_ID   Frame_ID      Distance  
        1        2        12            100  
        1        2        13        103  
        1        2        14        105  
        2        1        15        107  
     ***2        1        16        130  
        2        2        17        135***  
        2        2        18        136  
     ***3        1        19        140  
        3        2        20        141***  
        3        2        21        147  
        4        2        22        149  
     ***4        2        23        151
        4        1        24        154***
        4        1        25        159
```

With assistance from here i have sorted out those Vehicle_ID which have changed their lanes:

```
SELECT t.Vehicle_ID, COUNT(t.Lane_ID) AS [Lane Count]
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Vehicle_ID, Lane_ID FROM Table1
) AS t
GROUP BY t.Vehicle_ID
HAVING COUNT(t.Lane_ID) > 1
```

Shown Result:

```
Vehicle_ID  Lane Count  
       2    2  
       3    2  
       4    2
```

Now i want to do further analysis withe records of lane changing by segregating immediate two records: before and after lane change. My desired output would be:

Desired Result:

```
   Vehicle_ID   Lane_ID   Frame_ID      Distance  

     ***2        1        16        130  
        2        2        17        135***  
     ***3        1        19        140  
        3        2        20        141***  
     ***4        2        23        151
        4        1        24        154***
```

Comment: A "huge volume of data" and MS Access just don't belong together in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the frame ids have no gaps, you can do this using `join`s:

```
select t1.*
from (table1 as t1 inner join
      table1 as t1prev
      on t1prev.Vehicle_ID = t1.Vehicle_ID and
         t1prev.frame_id = t1.frame_id - 1             
     ) inner join
     table1 as t1next
     on t1next.Vehicle_ID = t1.Vehicle_ID and
        t1next.frame_id = t1.frame_id + 1           
where t1prev.lane_id <> t1.lane_id or
      t1next.lane_id <> t1.lane_id;
```

Otherwise, this will be a very expensive query.

Comment: Thank you Gordon..The syntax is ok. The output asked for "parameter V", when i click "ok" without giving any parameter value.. it return zero records.

Comment: @Tariq . . . Neither your question nor this answer have any parameters.  Further, there is no `V` in this answer that could be confused for a parameter.

Comment: ```where t1prev.lane_id <> t1.lane_id and  
      t1next.lane_id <> t1.lane_id;```

In this above lines of code changing the arithmetic symbol to "=" in upper line of code i get the previous record and in lower line of code i get the next records. I got it.. I really love you @Gordon. Thanks again

Comment: @tariq . . . That should be `or`, not `and`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
select t.* from Table1 t
where 
  exists (
    select 1 from Table1
    where 
      vehicle_id = t.vehicle_id 
      and 
      frame_id in (t.frame_id - 1, t.frame_id + 1) 
      and 
      lane_id <> t.lane_id
  )
```

Comment: @Fopas...Exactly i wanted this output..Thank you man. Regards

Comment: If this solved your problem consider accepting the answer